# How to count select distinct MySQL with 3 column

Tags: mysql, routines

I've a table like:

```
ID_USER USERNAME_USER REF_USER STATUS_AKTIF
1       a                      aktif
2       b             a        tidak
3       c             a        aktif
4       d             b        aktif
5       e             a        aktif
```

And I use this code:

```
select REF_USER, count(distinct USERNAME_USER) as TOTAL from TABLE where (REF_USER IS NOT NULL AND REF_USER!="" AND STATUS_AKTIF='aktif') group by REF_USER
```

But I only get:

```
REF_USER TOTAL
a        2
b        1
```

How I can remove b? Because user b STATUS_AKTIF is tidak

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a group by

```
SELECT count(*) as total, username_user FROM table 
WHERE (REF_USER IS NOT NULL AND REF_USER!="" AND STATUS_AKTIF='aktif') 
GROUP BY username_user
```

Comment: no, i try your code and it's just giving total for a and b = 1